# FormDigest control problems after September 10, 2019 Security Update

Tags: 2010, security, update

I've noticed some weird behaviour of Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FormDigest control after last security update.

Control is added to every page by setting following code in masterpage:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderFormDigest" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"/>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

At the top of masterpage file there is also a custom control added to validate POST requests:

[image]

When user with at least edit permission opens page, __REQUESTDIGEST input gets populated - but once user have less permissions it returns "noDigest":

[image]

I'm almost certain it worked just fine before last security update.
Does anyone know solution to get it back working?

//Edit: That's the whole correlation log for request to search page (with noDigest value in __REQUESTDIGEST field. Selected line looks interesting, but it doesn't originate from custom solution code - cannot find it there.
[image]

//Edit2: Full stacktrace of exception. 
[image]

//Edit3: Turned on Verbose logging. Full trace log available for download here: https://redbooth.com/d/ae58752e71a0c8c9

Comment: Can you turn on verbose logging and search for `FormDigest Control Render` in the ULS? If you find anything, look at all log entries with the same correlation ID.

Comment: @SlavenSemper Added full log for request. Does anything looks suspicious?

Comment: Can you post details (Message field) of those two exceptions?

Comment: @SlavenSemper added stacktrace. It looks like a classic error while checking form SPutility.ValidateFormDigest() (from control on 2nd screenshot)
Same stack for that "unexpected" trace.

I've also tried some DLL digging for shouldStampRequestDigest - looks like it originates from sharepoint dll. It looked for me like filling __REQUESTDIGEST  field is somehow connected with enabling output cache on site, but got no results fiddling with that.

Comment: You get this exception because digest is not present in rendered HTML. You need to figure out why it is empty. To do so, you need to enable verbose logging (Central Administration > Monitoring > Diagnostic Logging > select All Categories > Least critical event to report to the trace log > Verbose). Reproduce the issue. Then search for `FormDigest Control Render` in ULS.

Comment: @SlavenSemper Set verbose logging and added full request log to download. There is no "FormDigest Control Render" inside it, can't find anything suspicious too. It just doesn't get rendered without higher permissions.

Comment: We can continue on the chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99328/digest-control-discussion

Comment: Not enough reputation for chat yet, thats a fresh account :(

Comment: I have granted you write access now. You should be able to access the chat now.